# How to find unexisting file in folder?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with .mp4 files which i show online using web application. Rest of information about video file i taken from database.

I have n files in database and n-6 files in folder.

How do i find names of non existent files in folder using windows batch or cmd?

Answer (score 0):

this could be a bat script for you

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('SQL SELECT filename FROM directory') DO (
  IF EXIST %%a (
    ECHO %%a 
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO %%a NOT FOUND!
  )
)
```

Assuming your database has some way to query from the command line, substitute SQL commandline with the appropiate command (MYSQL, SQLCMD, DB2...) and use the actual SQL query statement appropiate for your schema.

Comment: i want to place query result to in () as i cannot access database from other server. How do i change it to work ? "IN ('[list of files delimited with ,]') DO" ?

Comment: see `HELP FOR`.. change the loop as `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (list.txt) DO `